# How to convert image to base64 in react-dropzone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I'm trying to implement react-dropzone on my app but I can't post and always get the **Internal Server Error**, and error: **TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'list'** in case data post must use convert base64

This is my onDrop function

```
onDrop(uploadData) {
  this.setState({
    uploadData,
  });
}
onDropHandler(uploadData) {
  var uploadData = uploadData[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(uploadData);
  reader.onload = event => {
    this.setState({
      uploadData: this.state.uploadData([{ base64: event.target.result }]),
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(uploadData);
}
```

and this is my render methods:

```
<div className="dropzone">
  <Dropzone
    onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
    accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg"
    onDrop={uploadData => {
      this.setState({ uploadData });
    }}
    maxSize={200000}
    multiple={false}
  >
    <p>Maksimal 2 MB (JPG/PNG)</p>
  </Dropzone>
  {this.state.uploadData.map(f => (
    <span key={f.name}>
      {f.name} - {f.size} bytes
    </span>
  ))}
</div>
```

[This is error pic after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgC6h.png)

[and this is json pic after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ewzz.png)

Comment: Please include error messages as text in your question. Include the **full traceback**. And also include the entire react class, not just some methods. What is `this.state.uploadData` here? Seems like it's a function? Why do you have a function in your state? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful

```
    const handleDrop = React.useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
      const file = acceptedFiles.find(f => f)
      let reader = new FileReader()

      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = () => {
        console.log({
          src: file.preview,
          data: reader.result
        })
        setB64(reader.result)
       }

     }, []);
```

Where `setB64` is a React `useState` Hook

Comment: Getting this error with this approach `Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`